# How to pass a C# struct by reference?

Tags: c#, c++, class, struct, ref

In my C# application I receive a pointer to a C++ struct in callback/delegate. I'm not sure if `class` can do the trick, but just casting a C++ pointer to an appropriate C# struct works fine, so I'm using a C# struct for storing data.

Now I want to pass a reference to the struct for further processing.

- I can't use `class` because it probably will not "map" perfectly to the C++ struct.
- I don't want to copy the struct for better latency.

How can I do that?

---

This example demonstrates that struct is passed by value, not by reference:

```
using System;

namespace TestStruct
{
    struct s
    {
        public int a;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            s s1 = new s
                       {
                           a = 1
                       };
            Foo(s1);
            Console.WriteLine("outer a = " + s1.a);
        }

        private static void Foo(s s1)
        {
            s1.a++;
            Console.WriteLine("inner a = " + s1.a);
        }

    }
}
```

Output is:

```
inner a = 2
outer a = 1
```

Comment: Beware of your reasoning about struct: `struct` in C++ is exactly the same as class (barring default accessibility), while in C# they are completely different - value and reference types. Chances are you really would be better of with classes in C# - at very least read and understand how `struct` behave in C#.

Comment: A large number of my interop classes are indeed classes and not structs. If you set up the marshalling correctly (and often the default marshalling works) then you can use a class. If in doubt, I try with a class first.

Comment: [Mutable structs are evil.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/441309/380384)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to use `ref` to pass the struct by reference:

```
private static void Foo(ref s s1)
{
    s1.a++;
    Console.WriteLine("inner a = " + s1.a);
}
```

And at the call site:

```
Foo(ref s1);
```

See my [article on parameter passing in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more details.

Note that other than for interop, I would normally strongly recommend *against* using mutable structs like this. I can understand the benefits here though.

Comment: +1. Side note: code handling `struct` must be written very carefully since almost all operations with `struct` create copy (except array, where you still can take a `ref` of an element).

Comment: Why do you strongly recommend against passing structs by `ref`? As far as I can tell, it's the same thing as passing by reference in C++ (eg. `std::string&`), and it can eliminate needless copying of potentially large structs.

Comment: @cmbasnett: I strongly recommended against using mutable structs. Passing a struct by ref is okay, but a) I would advise against large structs in general; b) I would argue against *mutable* structs (as do the Microsoft design guidelines) as they can cause a number of surprises.

Answer (score 0):

You can use c# 7.2 `in` keyword as follows:

```cs
static float Sample(in Vector3 v)
{
    // v.X = 2; // <-- this generate follow compiler error
    // error CS8332: Cannot assign to a member of variable 'v'
    // or use it as the right hand side of a ref assignment
    // because it is a readonly variable

    return v.X;
}
```

This ensures that struct argument v is:

- readonly
- passed by ref

### IL details

```cs
Vector3 v = Vector3.One;

float Sample(Vector3 v)
{
    return v.X;
}
System.Console.WriteLine(Sample(v));

float ReadonlySample(in Vector3 v)
{
    return v.X;
}
System.Console.WriteLine(ReadonlySample(v));
```

produce follow IL:

```
// Vector3 v2 = Vector3.One;
    IL_0001: call valuetype [System.Numerics.Vectors]System.Numerics.Vector3 [System.Numerics.Vectors]System.Numerics.Vector3::get_One()
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    // Console.WriteLine(Sample(v2));
    IL_0007: nop
    IL_0008: ldloc.0
    IL_0009: call float32 test_console.Sample::'<Main>g__Sample|0_0'(valuetype [System.Numerics.Vectors]System.Numerics.Vector3)
    IL_000e: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(float32)
    // (no C# code)
    IL_0013: nop
    // Console.WriteLine(ReadonlySample(in v2));
    IL_0014: nop
    IL_0015: ldloca.s 0
    IL_0017: call float32 test_console.Sample::'<Main>g__ReadonlySample|0_1'(valuetype [System.Numerics.Vectors]System.Numerics.Vector3&)
    IL_001c: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(float32)
```

you can see that using `in` we have [ldloca](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldloca?view=net-7.0) in place of [ldloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldloc?view=net-7.0).

In short the struct is passed like it was a `ref` but is protected to writes by the compiler thanks to the `in`.

Comment: When I write the post I missed to insert [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.2/readonly-ref) reference ; you can try yourself simply by changing language version in csproj, for example by setting `<LangVersion>6</LangVersion>` will produce following error for the same above code `error CS8059: Feature 'readonly references' is not available in C# 6. Please use language version 7.2 or greater.`